# I want to write a function that checks a 2-d List for duplicate elements

Tags: java

I want to write a function that checks a 2-d List for duplicate elements. For example: [[key1, key2], [key1, key3]] "key1" is duplicate. I want to remove or replace it e.g with n\a. What I have tried so far.

```
    private static List<List<String>> removeRedundantStrings(List<List<String>> list) {

        List<List<String>> outList = new ArrayList<>();

        List<String> oneDimension = new ArrayList<>();

        for (var tempList : list) {
            for (var string : tempList) {

                if (!oneDimension.contains(string))
                    oneDimension.add(string);

                else
                    oneDimension.add("n/a");

                outList.add(oneDimension);

            }

        }

        return outList;

    }
```

This "solution" results in: [[key1, key2, n/a, key3]] - not a "true" 2-d list. How would I achieve the same format as the input list? The result would be: [[key1, key2], [n/a, key3]]. Am I missing something else?

Comment: You need to instanciate oneDimension each time before the 2nd *for*, and add oneDim to outList when the 2nd for closes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create the inner List in the correct place - inside the outer loop.

In addition, I'd use a single `HashSet` to keep track of the `String`s that already appeared.

```
List<List<String>> outList = new ArrayList<>();
Set<String> uniques = new HashSet<>();

for (var tempList : list) {
    List<String> oneDimension = new ArrayList<>();
    for (var string : tempList) {
        if (uniques.add(string)) // add will return true if string was actually added to Set
            oneDimension.add(string);
        else
            oneDimension.add("n/a");
        }
    }
    outList.add(oneDimension);
}
```

Comment: I had a typo which I fixed.